# Is there a way to run short bits of Java code without compiling?

Tags: java

Is there a way to run or simulate running Java statements (kind of like IDLE - the Python GUI) without compiling and running the executable? I want to quickly test statements to see if they work. Thanks.

Comment: I vaguely recall somewhere that a newer version of java will make this possible

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep, you can use Eclipse, create a single project, and create a [Scrapbook Page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm) in that project.

[image]

You can also specify import statements: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31789&seqNum=3

> Scrapbook pages get their classpath
>   from the containing project's build
>   path. If in a scrapbook page you want
>   to reference a Java element that is
>   not on the build path of the
>   containing Java project, you need to
>   add to the Java project's build path.
>   Scrapbook pages also allow you to
>   specify import statements. You do this
>   by selecting Set Imports from the
>   context menu of a scrapbook page or
>   Set Import Declarations for Running
>   Code from the toolbar. You need to set
>   import statements for references to
>   Java declarations in your projects.
>   This is a common oversight. If the
>   type or package you are attempting to
>   import is not listed in the Add
>   dialog, it means you need to add it to
>   the build path of the project
>   containing the scrapbook page. If you
>   are referencing an element that has
>   multiple declarations, you will need
>   to add an import statement to uniquely
>   identify the element.

Edit: Got another solution too: http://ideone.com. It's an online IDE and debugging tool. You can see an example here: http://ideone.com/98sA8, but it looks like you have to set up a bit more than on a scrapbook page.

Edit 2:

Nowadays in Java 11, if it's a simple app in a single file you can run it directly from the java command (on the command line) which will handle all the compilation for you behind the scenes:

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

This is useful for students, as they can get started with Java without learning all of the `javac` compilation routine.

Comment: The scrapbook *does* compile the code before running. The OP specifically asked about a solution which does *not* compile the code. Personally, I don't understand why the OP would care about how the REPL is implemented, but those are his requirements.

Comment: He also mentions compiling and running executables, and executables don't exist in Java :) Anyway, I think the only way is to run Java is to compile it, it's a compiled language. Otherwise, the syntax would be different. This solution seems fairly simple enough. It also allows testing of statements quickly, and no .class files are created.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to Java so I don't know the proper terminology. Thank you for the excellent points.

Comment: Nowadays in Java 11, if it's a simple app in a single file you can run it directly from the `java` command which will handle all the compilation for you behind the scenes:

`java HelloWorld.java` etc.

Answer (score 10):

As of Java 11 (JEP 330) it is now possible to run Java files directly with the java tool:

```
java Factorial.java 3 4 5

is informally equivalent to

javac -d <memory> Factorial.java
java -cp <memory> Factorial 3 4 5
```

Java also added support for "shebang" files.

For more details see:
http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Answer (score 6):

Using Eclipse, you can create a Scrapbook page which will allow you to do exactly this.

Caveats:

1. You need to use full binary class names for anything outside of `java.lang`
2. You need to select the code (standard text selection) that you want to run
3. There are three different methods for running -- Inspect, Display, and Run. Inspect and Display are virtually the same, showing you the result of the last statement in your code (so you don't need to print it or anything), Run runs the selected code and dumps any output to the console view.

Answer (score 4):

Never used it, but [BeanShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeanShell) seems to do what you want

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use Beanshell to do this:

http://www.beanshell.org/download.html

Your other alternative, if you're using Eclipse, is to make use of the scrapbook functionality:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with [Groovy and the Groovy Console](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console), with the caveat that you'd need to know how to express whatever you are trying to express in Java in the Groovy language:

[image: Groovy Console]

Comment: Actually, you can copy and paste java code into a groovy script and just run it without changing any code. I do this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to checkout janino http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home also ..

Answer (score 0):

[JGrasp](http://www.jgrasp.org/) is the best solution. There is a thing called interactions, that's perfectly fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm), which is included by default starting from JDK 9. It is command-line based Read Eval Print Loop (REPL), where you can enter Java code, and get the results immediately.

[image: JShell]